# SpringData JPA - Provided id of the wrong type for class . Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

i'm facing this issue while using Spring JPA and trying to retrieve a List of objects.

This is the class i'm trying to retrieve

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OBJECTSTERMIC")
public class TermicObject {

    @Id
    @Column(name="TERMICID")
    private long termicId;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="OBJECTID",columnDefinition="INTEGER")
    private Object object;

    @Column(name="CONTECA_RIF")
    private int contecaRif;

    @Column(name="CONTECA_VAL")
    private int contecaVal;

    @Column(name="TYPE")
    private String type;

//getters and setters
```

The `Object` class has the primary key on MySQL stored as an Integer, indeed this is Object

```
@Entity
public class Object {

    @Column(name="OBJECTID")
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("OBJECTID")
    private int objectId;
    ....
```

So, nowhere is set a Long...

Now, i simply call in a service class

```
@Override
    public List<TermicObject> findAll() {

        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

and got this exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class it.besmart.db_eipo.persistence.model.Object. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class it.besmart.db_eipo.persistence.model.Object. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long
```

Where is set that Object Id should be Long?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at definition of your repository. Does it have right generic type? do you have Integer as second parameter? IMHO this can be root cause. See proposed correct version:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface TermicObjectRepository extends JpaRepository<TermicObject, Integer> {
    public Optional<TermicObject> findById(Integer id);
    public List<TermicObject> findAll()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per @Lubo's answer, in my case I was having compatibility issues between String and Long types and as my model required a Long autogenerated id I had to **change the repository** from

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {
}
```

to

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

And my controller from

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/products/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id) {
    productRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/products/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable(name = "id") Long id) {
    productRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define your id as a Long datatype.

```
@Id
@Column(name="TERMICID")
private Long termicId;
```

also make a change in your repository interface:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got this because

```
public class MyEntity {
  @Id()
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private int id;  // <-------- int

  ...

  public long getId() { return id; } // <-------- long

}
```

Comment: I was facing the same exception, I didn't notice that I had declared a type long for the child's id field. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 Long.valueOf(intValue)
```

to cast int to Long type because you define type Long to @Id

Comment: Where should this be added? In the question, there is a call for `repository.findAll()`, so no parameter is provided/required.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure, but I think this mapping

```
@Id
@Column(name="TERMICID")
private long termicId;

@MapsId
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="OBJECTID",columnDefinition="INTEGER")
private Object object;
```

Makes the id of the `Object` match the value of `termicId` which is a long.